# Pair strings in list based on containing text in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm looking to take a list of strings and create a list of tuples that groups items based on whether they contain the same text.

For example, say I have the following list:

```
MyList=['Apple1','Pear1','Apple3','Pear2']
```

I want to pair them based on all but the last character of their string, so that I would get:

```
ListIWant=[('Apple1','Apple3'),('Pear1','Pear2')]
```

We can assume that only the last character of the string is used to identify. Meaning I'm looking to group the strings by the following unique values:

```
>>> list(set([x[:-1] for x in MyList]))
['Pear', 'Apple']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [69]: from itertools import groupby

In [70]: MyList=['Apple1','Pear1','Apple3','Pear2']

In [71]: [tuple(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(MyList, key=lambda x: x[:-1]), lambda x: x[:-1])]
Out[71]: [('Apple1', 'Apple3'), ('Pear1', 'Pear2')]
```

Comment: I believe you'd want to use the same `key` function for the `sorted` call as you do for the `groupby` call, otherwise you'll break up groups when the inputs are something like `"Apple1", "Apple12", "Apple3"`, because even though the `groupby` `key` function would group `Apple1` with `Apple3`, `Apple12` would sort in between and break up the group, preventing `groupby` from seeing that the two belong together (it only processes groups formed by consecutive values).

Comment: Right you are. Adding that in now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
   def alphagroup(lst):
      results = {}
      for i in lst:
         letter = i[0].lower()
         if not letter in results.keys():
            results[letter] = [i,]
         else:
            results[letter].append(i)
      output = []
      for k in results.keys():
         res = results[k]
         output.append(res)
      return output

   arr = ["Apple1", "Pear", "Apple2", "Pack"];

   print alphagroup(arr);
```

This will achieve your goal. If each element must be a tuple, use the tuple() builtin in order to convert each element to a tuple. Hope this helps; I tested the code.